Magnetic Dipole Derivation
$\oint (\hat{r}\cdot \vec{r}') d\vec{l} $ is what I get as part of the magnetic dipole term, but I can reduce this to $ -\vec{r}' \times \int d\vec{a}' $. I don't understand how you can reduce it to this. Griffiths says you can use $ \int_{S}^{} \nabla T \times d\vec{a} = -\oint_{P} T \cdot d\vec{l} $ and derive $ \oint (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{r}) d\vec{l}=\vec{a} \times \vec{c} $ by putting $ T=\vec{c} \cdot \vec{r} $ and the $ \vec{c} $ here is $ \hat{r} $. Could someone help me with the whole derivation?
Sorry about the bad formatting, this is my first time using LaTeX and I hope I made enough contextual sense.
